# How to reduce data frame to sum of distinct combinations

Tags: r, combinations

I have following type of data (pairs of countries + their

```
set.seed(123)
data.frame(V1=c(rep('a',2), rep('b',2), rep('c',2)), V2=c('b', 'c', 'a', 'c', 'a', 'b'), V3=round(runif(6), 2))
  V1 V2   V3
  a  b    0.29
  a  c    0.79
  b  a    0.41
  b  c    0.88
  c  a    0.94
  c  b    0.05
```

I would like to sum up the last column for paired combinations so I have following result

```
combn(letters[1:3], 2) %>% t %>% as.data.frame() %>% cbind(V3=c(0.7, 1.73, 0.93))
  V1 V2   V3
  a  b    0.70
  a  c    1.73
  b  c    0.93
```

I suppose it would be easy if I converted the first data frame into a nice matrix but I am not sure on how to do that.

Comment: `aggregate(V3~V1+V2, df, sum)`

Comment: The `aggregate` or `tapply` functions are so simple and typical of what would ordinarily be taught in an introduction to R, that asking this question makes us wonder whether you have made much of an effort with tutorials. The CRAN website has an extensive list of tutorial material. https://cran.r-project.org/other-docs.html ; https://www.r-project.org/other-docs.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `pmin` and `pmax` to sort columns `V1` + `V2` by row, then do the aggregate:

```
with(df, aggregate(V3, list(V1=pmin(V1, V2), V2 = pmax(V1, V2)), sum))

#  V1 V2    x
#1  a  b 0.70
#2  a  c 1.73
#3  b  c 0.93
```

Note: in order for `pmin`, `pmax` to work, `V1` and `V2` has to be character vectors instead of factor, here is the data I am using:

```
set.seed(123)
df = data.frame(V1=c(rep('a',2), rep('b',2), rep('c',2)), 
                V2=c('b', 'c', 'a', 'c', 'a', 'b'), 
                V3=round(runif(6), 2), stringsAsFactors = F)
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
   group_by(g1 = pmin(V1, V2), g2 = pmax(V1, V2)) %>% 
   summarise(V3 = sum(V3))
#      g1    g2    V3
#   <chr> <chr> <dbl>
#1     a     b  0.70
#2     a     c  1.73
#3     b     c  0.93
```